# Getting an EXC_BAD_ACCES error running app template code

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sfml

### Preliminary Details:

- OS X 10.11
- Xcode 7.2
- SFML 2.3.2
- Clang C++11
- Default SFML App template

### Problem:

I have just done a fresh install of SFML, I double checked and triple checked all of the required files are in the correct places.

When I build and run the stock, SFML App template for Xcode, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line 81 of this file (Line 81: `window.draw(sprite);` - also commented clearly):

```
//
// Disclamer:
// ----------
//
// This code will work only if you selected window, graphics and audio.
//
// Note that the "Run Script" build phase will copy the required frameworks
// or dylibs to your application bundle so you can execute it on any OS X
// computer.
//
// Your resource files (images, sounds, fonts, ...) are also copied to your
// application bundle. To get the path to these resource, use the helper
// method resourcePath() from ResourcePath.hpp
//

#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

// Here is a small helper for you ! Have a look.
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"

int main(int, char const**)
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

    // Set the Icon
    sf::Image icon;
    if (!icon.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "icon.png")) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    window.setIcon(icon.getSize().x, icon.getSize().y, icon.getPixelsPtr());

    // Load a sprite to display
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "cute_image.jpg")) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

    // Create a graphical text to display
    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "sansation.ttf")) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    sf::Text text("Hello SFML", font, 50);
    text.setColor(sf::Color::Black);

    // Load a music to play
    sf::Music music;
    if (!music.openFromFile(resourcePath() + "nice_music.ogg")) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Play the music
    music.play();

    // Start the game loop
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // Close window: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }

            // Escape pressed: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        // Clear screen
        window.clear();

        // Draw the sprite
        window.draw(sprite); // -------------- LINE 81

        // Draw the string
        window.draw(text);

        // Update the window
        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### What I've Tried

I have searched online (including SO posts), the common cause seems to be some kind of stack overflow. But I can't see what would cause a stack overflow in the above program with my knowledge.

Comment: You are sure that you have the Platform library visible to your application during runtime?  It may be there when you link the libraries into the executable, but not in the executable folder.  This is usually thrown when an application is trying to access a memory location that no longer exist or is not within the mem boundaries of the app.

Comment: Forget that last statement...  Can you draw the text (comment out draw(sprite)?

Answer (score 0):

If you look for this kind of error of SFML's forums, you'll see that it was always due to some old header/binary files being present on the system and being used instead of the newer ones.

Make sure that you removed *all* versions of SFML before installing the latest one. As per [Installing SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-osx.php#installing-sfml) tutorial, you need to look in:

- `/usr/local/include`
- `/usr/local/lib`
- `/Library/Frameworks`